# Controller does not send data to view, arrives as null

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I've been trying to send data from controller to view in CodeIgniter 4, let me just...

Model:

```php
class KomikModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'komik';
    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $allowedFields = ['judul', 'slug', 'penulis', 'penerbit', 'sampul'];

    public function getKomik($slug = false)
    {
        if ($slug == false) {
            return $this->findAll();
        }

        return $this->where(['slug' => $slug])->first();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
    public function edit($slug)
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Form Ubah Data',
            'validation' => \Config\Services::validation(),
            'komik' => $this->komikModel->getKomik($slug)
        ];

        return view('komik/edit', $data);
    }
```

View:

```php
<?= dd($komik); ?>
```

After all that, $komik that arrived in the view comes out as null. Why, what did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

PS: Somehow, it works fine with other methods. currently there are 3 other methods using the model to send data from controller towards the view. but only at this edit method the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this particular line.

```
 return $this->where(['slug' => $slug])->first();
```

Model Class doesn't have any "where" method defined in it. It borrows it from Builder Class. This is called object composition. You can certainly try to have your own method with a similar implementation as in the Model class but I would recommend against it since it is an antipattern.

A better approach would be to have a single class that is responsible for all the querying or filtering as in Repository Pattern. You can do a bit of research on that.